# How to call method in state class in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to call the method from HomeState class to _MyHomePageState class.But i have no idea to do that.

this is main.dart :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Home home = new Home();  
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(         
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){}
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

Home class:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return HomeState();
  }
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {

  int numberPrint(){
    setState((){});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
  }
}
```

I want to call the method numberPrint() in floatingbutton in _MyHomePageState class in main.dart.
Please help me to do that.

Comment: pass in a function as a parameter to your HomePage, your'e thinking very very much outside the box

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at how I would have handled, this is not the best, but it would give you a better idea.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
//MyHomePage---------------------------------------------------
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  MyController controller = MyController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
Home home = new Home(controller:controller);  
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(         
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: controller.execute,
      ), 
    );
  }
}
//Home---------------------------------------------------------------------
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({this.controller});
  final MyController controller;
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return HomeState();
  }
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  initState(){
    widget.controller.addListener(numberPrint);
  }
  
  numberPrint(){
    setState((){});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
  }
}

//MyController--------------------------------------------------------
class MyController{
  Function listener;
  addListener(Function fn){
    listener = fn;
  }
  
  execute(){
    listener();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think he was trying to ask specifically how to update the child from the parent, instead of the parent from the child like you've done.

Comment: Oh sorry.. But my answer can be applied to that approach as well.. I'll update the answer to match the question

Answer (score 0):

In general, I use some kind of page nerve center through which widgets can register their `setState` functions or other things such as `FocusNode` and even data.

For example,

```
class PageNerveCenter{
  Function requireHomeRebuild;
}

PageNerveCenter _pageNerveCenter = PageNerveCenter();

class Home extends StatefulWidget{...}

class _HomeState extends State<Home>{

...
  @override
  initState(){
    super.initState();
    // register setState 
    _pageNerveCenter.requireHomeRebuild = (){
      setState((){}) 
    };
  }

  @override
  dispose(){
    // remove setState when object is disposed
    _pageNerveCenter.requireHomeRebuild = (){};
  }

...

}
```

In some other widget (same file/library),

```
_pageNerveCenter.requireHomeRebuild();
```

This approach then allows you to call a widget's `setState` from anywhere in the file, from inside another widget.

In my own experience, this approach has helped to easily break down my widget tree and only rebuild those widgets that actually need to rebuilt too.

I would certainly like to hear other more experienced flutter developers about their take on this approach since I am relatively new too.